# Struggling with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following model:

[image]

I've been at this for a while and still don't know how to tackle it properly. Already looked at joining two aliased subqueries, joining two views, and tried a gynormous and ugly all-in one query, none of which worked.

My question is simple:

How can I select deivce_names.name and match them to a model and manufacturer?

Comment: You have to join all of your 5 tables. Maybe you should re-design it to have fewer tables, at least in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    name, manufacturer, model
FROM
    device_names
    JOIN devices ON (device_names.id = name_id)
    JOIN devices_generic ON (generic_device_id = devices_generic.id)
    JOIN device_manufacturers ON (manufacturer_id = device_manufacturers.id)
    JOIN device_models ON (model_id = device_models.id)
```

Comment: "Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'device_manufacturers'"

Comment: The answerer forgot aliases. `JOIN device_manufacturers dm1 ON (manufacturer_id = dm1.id)
    JOIN device_manufacturers dm2 ON (model_id = device_models.id)`

Comment: @Patashu aliases are not required; problem was I typed "device_manufacturers" instead of "device_models" for the last table, but I have corrected that in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    device_names.name as device_name,
    device_manufacturers.name as device_manufacturer_name,
    device_models.name as device_model_name
from deivce_names
join device on device.name_id = deivce_names.id
join devices_generic on devices_generic.id = devices.generic_device_id
join device_manufacturers on devices_generic.manufacturer_id = device_manufacturers.id
join device_models on device_models.id = devices_generic.model_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT dm1.manufacturer, dm2.model from device_manufacturers as dm1 join devices_generic as dg on dg.manufacturer_id = dm1.id join device_models as dm2 on dm2.id = dg.model_id join devices as d2 on d2.generic_device_id = dg.id join device_names as dn on dn.id = d2.name_id where name = 'foo'`

In the future, you might want to simply put your data into a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and play with it there.